# Making a hyperlink in ASP

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need another set of eyes on this line of code, I would like to make it a hyperlink and pass the agency id through, although I don't see the hyperlink showing up. Can someone take a look, thanks.

```
    $('#agency' + parentAgency.id).append(
    '<li id="listItem' + agency.id + '" data-level="' + 
     agency.level + '" data-position="' + agency.position + '">' 
  + '<a href="agency.aspx?agencyid="' + agency.id + '>' + agency.name 
  + '</a>' + '</li>');
```

Comment: please upload your full code

Comment: Is this in a click handler? can you `console.log(parentAgency.id)` and then `console.log($('#agency<parentid>'))` with the parentId to ensure your selector is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please review this code

```
 $('#agency' + parentAgency.id).append('<li id="listItem' + agency.id + '" data-level="' + agency.level + '" data-position="' + agency.position + '"><a href="agency.aspx?agencyid="' + agency.id + '>' + agency.name + '</a></li>');
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a cleaner way to write it, but still no result.